# Stop a program from running in c++ if bool is false

Tags: c++, boolean, return, exit

I am using an if statement to get the users input with a bool value, if they enter 1 then the program continues to execute, if they enter 0 then I want the program to stop running completely. This is the code im using.

```
bool subscription;
cout << "Would you like to purchase a subscription to our newspaper?\n";
cout << "Enter 1 if yes, and 0 if no. ";
cin >> subscription;

if(subscription == false)
{
   cout << "We're sorry you don't want our services.";
   //this is where i want the program to stop, after it outputs that line.
}
else if(subscription == true)
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter your first and last name. ";
}
```

I have tried using `return 0;` after the `cout` statement, but that didn't work, it would just output the statement and then continue on with the program.

I also tried `exit();` and that did the exact same thing.

Comment: `if(subscription = false)` - did you really mean `if(subscription == false)` ?

Comment: I would compile this will full warnings, these will tell you the issue

Comment: Yes, thats what i meant, but i dont think that solves the problem.

Comment: Is this code in main function? Did you try exit(0) ? You mean your application doesn't exit?

Comment: `exit(0)` should work. If you want an abnormal process termination you can use `abort()` both functions are in `cstdlib`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that instead of the comparison operator you are using the assignment operator

```
if(subscription = false)
{
cout << "We're sorry you don't want our services.";
//this is where i want the program to stop, after it outputs that line.
}
else if(subscription = true)
{
cout << "\nPlease enter your first and last name. ";
}
```

In thsi expression of the if statement

```
if(subscription = false)
```

you assigned false to subscription and the expression is also equal to false. As the result the compound statement of this if statement is not executed.

Change the  code as

```
if(subscription == false)
{
cout << "We're sorry you don't want our services.";
//this is where i want the program to stop, after it outputs that line.
}
else if(subscription == true)
{
cout << "\nPlease enter your first and last name. ";
}
```

It would be even better if you would write

```
if( subscription )
{
    cout << "\nPlease enter your first and last name. ";
}
else 
{
    cout << "We're sorry you don't want our services.";
    // here you can place the return statement
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but to make the program stop there all i had to do was include return 0; after fixing the ==.

Comment: @Christoph Yes, you are right. I pointed it in the comment of the last code example.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool subscription;
    cout << "Would you like to purchase a subscription to our newspaper?"<<endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 if yes, and 0 if no. "<<endl;
    cin >> subscription;
    if(!subscription){
        cout << "We're sorry you don't want our services."<<endl;
        //this is where i want the program to stop, after it outputs that line.
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "\nPlease enter your first and last name. "<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

A couple of guidelines:

1. Do not use var = true or var = false (use double == for comparison)
2. Do not user boolean variables var == true in comparisons with true or false, just use them directly as boolean conditions
3. Put "<<"endl" when using streams for line breaks better than \n
4. Use return in main function will return in that place, thus finishing your program.